# All QT GUI applications fail with SEG FAULT on debian

Tags: linux, qt, segmentation-fault, gdb, debian

I recently installed Debian. Unfortunately all software that depends on QT GUI exits with `Segmentation fault` immediately after launch. After running gdb, the output I received is:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/Fritzing 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff6073344 in QString::operator==(QLatin1String const&) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff6073303 in QString::operator==(QLatin1String const&) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x00007ffff613a019 in QCoreApplication::libraryPaths() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#2  0x00007ffff613a4d8 in QCoreApplication::init() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#3  0x00007ffff613a536 in QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#4  0x00007ffff69bc502 in QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#5  0x000000000049ae0f in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000004467bc in ?? ()
#7  0x00007ffff51e8b45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x446780, argc=1, 
    argv=0x7fffffffde98, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffde88) at libc-start.c:287
#8  0x0000000000478ba8 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Unfortunately when I googled this error, no similar error show up.
I tried:

- Running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, no difference
- Went to synaptic and made sure the libqt* installed libraries are the last version
- Removed and reinstalled libqt* packages

Can it be some problem related to encoding or similar thing, because of the `QLatin1String` in the error I pasted above?

ldd /usr/bin/Fritzing returns:

```
viktor@debian:~$ ldd /usr/bin/Fritzing
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd4abf4000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f09c8a3c000)
libQtSvg.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4 (0x00007f09c87e4000)
libQtSql.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSql.so.4 (0x00007f09c85a2000)
libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f09c835b000)
libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f09c766b000)
libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f09c7319000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f09c6e2a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f09c6c0d000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f09c6901000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f09c6600000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f09c63ea000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f09c603e000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f09c5e01000)
libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0x00007f09c5be6000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09c58d7000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f09c56b0000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f09c5406000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09c51b2000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f09c4faa000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f09c4d8d000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f09c4b82000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f09c4970000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f09c462d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f09c4428000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f09c4220000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056043e8f9000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f09c3ff6000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f09c3d8d000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f09c3b89000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f09c391a000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f09c3712000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f09c350d000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f09c32ea000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f09c30e5000)
```

Comment: Is it possible the application was compiled against a different version of Qt than the one you have installed?

Comment: @MrEricSir I also tried purging all libqt packages and let the apps install the QT they need, still no effect.

Comment: Maybe try to check for deps with ldd and try to compile without Qt to make sure it is really related with this library.

Comment: @dgrat I'm using synaptic to install the ready-to-use binaries. Is there a way to test this without installing all of the development tools required for the mentioned apps, so I can compile it from source? Just added the return of ldd to the question.